# iOS: Application missing from Location Services list

Tags: ios, location

My application uses iPhone's GPS functionality, and it was working fine previously, as in it prompts user to allow the use of location services and it shows up under Settings > Location Services list. I uninstalled and re-downloaded the app from the app store, but it no longer does either of them. The app was of the same version, and hasn't been updated for a while, but the problem had started recently.

The problem has been found in multiple devices (iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S) running different OS (iOS 4-5). Did Apple change how Location Services work recently?

Answer (score 1):

This same happend to me and i don't know why. To restore applications to location service list you need to turn of main location service switch and then run all of your applications one by one. Every app which will need location service enabled will ask you to enable this service and add itself to the list.

Comment: I tired this, and it did not work for Messages. Driving me insane.

Comment: I just ran into a similar problem developing for iOS8; despite giving location services permissions to my app, it was unable to get a location. Every time I ran my app, the permissions disappeared. Long story short: turn off location services for the the entire device and then re-enable them. Why this fixed the issue, I cannot say (even rebooting the phone didn't solve the problem).